# missing some head files when use pytorch

Tags: pytorch, libtorch

[image]

I’ve installed PyTorch using the standard pip route, `pip install torch==1.10.1+cu102 torchvision==0.11.2+cu102 torchaudio==0.10.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

I am trying to include this file:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/jit/python/pybind_utils.h
```

However, when I try to compile my project, it seems to be missing this: torch/csrc/distributed/rpc/py_rref.h

And there is no subdirectory `distribuited` under directory `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you coding in python with pytorch or C++ with libtorch ? Because if C++, then pip is not the way to install libtorch : https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html